# Convert raster into shapefile with attributes

Tags: python, attributes, bing-maps, shapefile

I made this code in python 2.7 for downloading bing traffic flow map (specific area) every x minutes.

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image
import urllib
import time

i = 1
end = time.time() + 60*24*60
url = 'https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Map/AerialWithLabels/45.8077453%2C15.963863/17?mapSize=500,500&mapLayer=TrafficFlow&format=png&key=Lt2cLlR9OcfEnMLv5qyd~YbPpC6zOQdhTMcwsKCwlgQ~Am2YLG00hHI6h7W1IPq31VOzqEXKAhedzHfknCejIrdQF_iVrQS82AUdjBT0YMtt'

while True:

    buffer = StringIO(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
    image = Image.open(buffer)
    image.save('C:\Users\slika'+str(i)+'.png')
    i=i+1

    if time.time()>end:
        break

    time.sleep(60*10)
```

This is one of the images i got [traffic flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bamQU.png)

Now my question is can i convert only traffic flow lines (green,yellow, orange, red) and assign them attributes (1,2,3,4) or ('No traffic' , 'Light' , 'Moderate' , 'Heavy') into shape file for usage in QGIS. What modules should i look for and is it even possible. Any idea or sample code would be much helpful.

Comment: I believe that this is not possible, or if it is is highly complex as you currently are describing it. You are getting an image (raster) which has pixel values, and want to convert *some* of those pixels (that is a way to get them) into a vector format. The difficulty is that your color lines are obstructed by text and other stuff. You *may* try with raster2vector, or rasterize functions, but I don't think it can work. The thing is that you have to get *somehow* those traffic flow lines pixels and turn them to a vector.

Comment: What if i remove the text (name of streets ) could it be done then. And could i just assign attributes and get csv or other format which would show them?

Answer (score 0):

This is against the terms of use of Bing Maps.

Also, I notice that you are using a Universal Windows App key. Those keys are to only be used in public facing Windows apps that anyone has access to. These keys cannot be used in GIS/business apps. Use a Dev/Test key or upgrade to an Enterprise account.